# How to execute the remote machine cmd file or bat file from local machine using java

Tags: java, remote-desktop

```
try {
      String ip = "12.1.12.9";
    String userName = "test";
    String password = "Test";

      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdkey /generic:" + ip +
                                              " /user:" + userName +
                                              " /pass:" + password );
      p.destroy();
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mstsc /v: " + ip + " /f /console");
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C://Users//Admin2//Desktop//democmd.cmd");
      
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//i am able to login remote machine and able to see the `remote desktop` but i need to execute the `democmd.cmd` file automatically once login. but i am not able to trigger `democmd.cmd` file automatically.

Comment: I believe you need to have a programm running on the target mashine that accepts your request and start the process. A simple remote-shell, like in any hacking tutorial, should do. You could in theory open the java console and put in your commands there, but then the java console is the program taking your input

Comment: is there any way like simply, execute the cmd or bat file in remote machine from local machine by passing ip, username and password using java. because i don't want to make running program inside target machine. every thing should do in single time. thanks in advance